# Send an excel file as attachment from Flask app on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I'm working on a project using Flask in which I have to send an excel file to the user in return of a get request, I have deployed this app on Heroku.

Here's what I have tried:

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(username + ".xlsx")
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
row = 0
for tweet in tweets:
    worksheet.write_string(row, 0, str(tweet.id))
    worksheet.write_string(row, 1, str(tweet.created_at))
    worksheet.write(row, 2, tweet.text)
    worksheet.write_string(row, 3, str(tweet.in_reply_to_status_id))
    row += 1
workbook.close()
print("Excel file ready")
try:
    filename = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    print(filename)
    return send_from_directory(filename, filename=username+'.xlsx', as_attachment=True)
except FileNotFoundError:
    abort(404)
```

But I'm not able to get the generated file.

Comment: Have you considered using a download tag in your html frontend, and then having the user download the file when its ready? Seems simpler; also can you specify what you mean by “your not able to get the generated file”?

Comment: Actually, there' no frontend html I have, it's a simple an endpoint where your send a get request and will get this files downloaded.

Comment: Okay, but can you clarify what happens when this doesnt work;; do you get an error? A blank page? What happens that you dont want to happen

Comment: it should return the excel file (download to the browser), but it'd not.

Comment: What does it return instead?

Comment: nothing but in the logs I can the last statement printed.

Comment: I see whats wrong. Ur using __filename___ which returns the file name of the python file your running, not the name of the excel file you want to send

Comment: It's printing the file path not just the name, I think there's something else is wrong.

Comment: I also think @MichaelIlie is right here, 

for the call to `send_from_directory` your are using `filename` as parameter, which is set via `__file__`. 

You should use the workbook filename.